# Drools Excel decision table and line break in a cell

Tags: excel, drools, kie

I am using Drools 6.2.0.Final and Excel decision tables to define rules.

Everything works fine, but if I try to use a break line within a cell (alt+enter in Excel) I get the following exception on rules compilation

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while creating KieBase[Message [id=1, level=ERROR, path=myrules/objects.xls, line=6, column=0
   text=Rule Compilation error String literal is not properly closed by a double-quote]]
    at org.drools.compiler.kie.builder.impl.KieContainerImpl.getKieBase(KieContainerImpl.java:395)
    at org.kie.spring.KieObjectsResolver.resolveKBase(KieObjectsResolver.java:33)
    at org.kie.spring.factorybeans.KBaseFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(KBaseFactoryBean.java:162)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1573)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1511)
    ... 50 more
```

Is there any way to use a break line within a cell for rule definition?

Answer (score 1):

After several tries I have found a workaround for this problem.
I share it if someone else have the same problem

You have to add to the table header

```
EscapeQuotes    false
```

and use the following syntax in the cell

```
Line 1"+
"Line 2"+
"Line 3
```